# How to standardize the bag of words for train and test?

Tags: nlp, nltk

I am trying to classify based on the bag-of-words model from NLP.

1. Did pre-processing of the train data using NLTK (punctuation, stop words removal, lower case, stemming etc.)
2. Created tf-idf matrix for train.
3. Did pre-processing of test.
4. Created tf-idf matrix for test data.
5. Train and Test data have different bag of words so the no of features are different, so we cannot use a classification algo like knn.
6. I merged the train and test data together and created the tf-idf matrix. This solved the above problem of different bag of words. But the resultant matrix was too huge to process.

Here are my questions:

1. Is there a way to create the exact bag of words for train and test?
2. If there is not and my approach of adding train and test is correct, should I go for a dimensionality reduction algo like LDA?

Comment: see here [CountVectorizer](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.CountVectorizer.html)

Answer (score 2):

You may use the scikit learn's count vectorizer to first create vectors for given words in the document, use it to train a classifier of your choice and then use the classifer to test your data.

For the training set, you can use the vectorizer to train the data as follows:

```
 LabeledWords=pd.DataFrame(columns=['word','label'])

 LabeledWords.append({'word':'Church','label':'Religion'} )

 vectorizer = CountVectorizer()

 Xtrain,yTrain=vectorizer.fit_transform(LabeledWords['word']).toarray(),vectorizer.fit_transform(LabeledWords['label']).toarray()
```

You can then train the classifier of your choice with the above vectorizer like:

```
forest = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators = 100) 
clf=forest.fit(Xtrain,yTrain)
```

In order to test your data:

```
for each_word,label in Preprocessed_list:
    test_featuresX.append(vectorizer.transform(each_word),toarray())
    test_featuresY.append(label.toarray())
clf.score(test_featuresX,test_featuresY)
```

Comment: Thank you for this. If I am not mistaken this is the same way one can train a Bag of Visual words, by creating the codebook (clusters using knn) of features for the training set. Then predicting the histograms of the test images, using the same codebook and passing that in to your classifier.